# Checking where $\frac{1}{z^5-1}$ is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I want to check where $\frac{1}{z^5-1}$  and $|z|\sin(z)$ are differentiable.

My question is:

is there any other (analytic) way to check it other than multiplying  with its  conjugate and +1 and doing a slow and painful process of expanding the binomial for the first one?

Also, any hints on the second one would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the second one, you could try checking Cauchy-Riemann equations : You know that $|z|= \sqrt{x^2+y^2} , sin(z)= sin(x)cosh(y) + icos(x)sinh(y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, I would do as follows:

- since $z\mapsto z$ is differentiable and the product of differentiable functions is differentible, $z\mapsto z^5$ is differentiable;
- since the sum of differentiable functions is differentiable and since constant functions are differentiable, $z\mapsto z^5-1$ is differentiable;
- since the multiplicative inverse of a differentiable function is differentiable, $z\mapsto\frac1{z^5-1}$ is differentiable.

So, the answer is: the function is differentiable at every point of its domain, which is $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\text{fifth roots of }1\}$.

Comment: Can a Function be differentiable but not continuous? What happens when the denominator is equal to 0?

Comment: Just as in the case of real analysis, differentiability $\implies$ continuity. If we have a $0$ in the denominator, the function isn't defined there.

Comment: Your answer makes it seem like the function is differentiable at all points (because $z^5-1$ is differentiable at all points. I think it would be clearer if you edit it.

Comment: @JonathanPerales It is done.

Comment: That edit completes the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the second one, it's probably easiest to use the [Cauchy-Riemann conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).  If we write a complex-valued function as $f(x +iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, then $f$ is complex-differentiable if and only if
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \qquad \& \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.
$$
For this function, we have
$$
f(x + iy) = |x + iy| \sin (x + iy) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \left[ \sin x \cos (iy) + \cos x \sin(iy) \right] \\ = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \left[ \sin x \cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y \right].
$$
Take it from here.  The conditions on $x$ and $y$ that emerge are not the easiest to solve, but assuming I did the problem correctly when I worked through it, there are a countably infinite number of points where the function is differentiable.

Comment: I support this solution for the second problem. Seems to be the only one, and yes, it will be a painful and slow process.

Comment: You are right, I fixated on the origin but the pathology in the second one is spread over everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, the answer by Santos is OK but it leaves out the five points at which the function blows up and is not differentiable, namely, at 
$$
\begin{array}{l} z = 1 \\ z = \frac14 (\sqrt{5}-1) + \sqrt{\frac18} i\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}} \\  \frac14 (-\sqrt{5}-1) + \sqrt{\frac18} i\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}} \\
-\frac14 (-\sqrt{5}-1) + \sqrt{\frac18} i\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}} \\
\frac14 (\sqrt{5}-1) -\sqrt{\frac18} i\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}
\end{array}
$$
which are the five fifth roots of $1$.

The second function, $|z| \sin z$ is also subtle.  Clearly it is differentiable at any $z \neq 0$ but does the function $\sin z$ go to zero rapidly enough to render it differentiable at $z = 0$?  (For example, $|z|$ is not differentiable at $z=0$.)

I believe the answer is that $|z| \sin z$ is differentiable at $z=0$ for the same reason that the real function $x|x|$ has a well-defined derivative equal to $0$ at $x=0$.  If that is right, then is the function $|z| \sin z$ analytic everywhere? That which certainly makes me uncomfortable, but there it is...